# If $\lceil\frac{x}{3}\rceil < \lceil\frac{y}{3}\rceil$ what can you conclude about $x$ and $y$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Certainly if there were no ceiling functions around I would know what that inequality implies. I'm just not sure what else I have to be worried about.

My intuition tells me that I should just be able to conclude that $x<y$, however I'm concerned there's more to the ceiling function than meets the eye. I know that if the input is an integer the function will return itself, if it's not an integer it will round up to the nearest integer.

Edit: Certainly if $x<y$ then it's not necessarily true that $\lceil\frac{x}{3}\rceil < \lceil\frac{y}{3}\rceil$. For example take $x=2$ and $y=3$, obviously $x<y$ but $\lceil\frac{x}{3}\rceil = \lceil\frac{y}{3}\rceil$.

Comment: The $x,y$ for which one or both of the ceilings change (from left to right) are the integers of form $3k,$ with $k$ an integer. Maybe can use that to get somewhere toward an answer.

Comment: "My intuition tells me that I should just be able to conclude that $x < y$." Try proof by contradiction.  Can $x$ be $\geq y$?  While the ceiling function is not continuous, it **is strictly non-decreasing**.

Answer (score 3):

The most general conclusion you can draw is that there exists an integer $n$ such that $x\le 3n< y$.

Answer (score 1):

Your edit gets the implication backwards.  It is true that if $\lceil \frac x3 \rceil \lt \lceil \frac y3 \rceil$ then $x \lt y$.  It is not true that if $x \lt y$ then $\lceil \frac x3 \rceil \lt \lceil \frac y3 \rceil$, which your example shows.  You can add $x \lt y-1$ to the conclusion when $x \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ or $y \equiv 1 \pmod 3$